# Element not visible RobotframeWork

Tags: javascript, selenium, robotframework

I am working with Robot FW for the first time and am facing an issue.
I Have a button and I try clicking on it.

```
<section id="block-righticonblock">
  <section block clearfix>
    <button aria-hidden="true" class="align-right icon icon-share hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md btn btn-link" data-target="#social-share" data-toggle="collapse" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" id="ui-collapse-890">
    </button>
  </section>
</section>
```

I am receiving an exception **Element Not Visible**

Can anyone explain why and a possible solution?

- Can I force seleniumLibrary to ignore the non-visible state of the elements?
- How can I force SeleniumLibrary to interact with the non-visible element?
- Can I use javascript to change the visibility of the aria-hidden?

Comment: Code trials and error stack trace (if any) please.

Comment: If the element is invisible, the user can't click on it. If the user can't click on it, neither can selenium.

Comment: Adding to what @BryanOakley mentioned. If the element is not **displayed** (invisible) i.e. `height and width not greater than 0` neither _user_ nor _Selenium_ can interact. But I would still say without the code trial and error stack trace debugging/answering to such questions are pretty tough.